# COPY INTO statement threw 110806;A distributed query failed

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am trying to do a COPY INTO statement for about 10 files of size 100mb each that are stored in the data lake, and it keeps throwing this error;
Msg 110806, Level 11, State 0, Line 7

```
110806;A distributed query failed: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Operation cancelled by user.

The command i used is;

```
COPY INTO AAA.AAAA FROM 'https://AAAA.blob.core.windows.net/data_*.csv' WITH (
                        CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'MANAGED IDENTITY'), FIELDQUOTE = N'"', FIELDTERMINATOR = N',',FIRSTROW = 2 );
```

where did i go wrong? please advise.

Comment: Can you confirm if your table is an internal table (which I would expect to work) or an external table (I'm not sure if that would work), what DWU you are running at, what the distribution of the table is (round robin, hash, replicate), what the indexing of the table is (clustered columnstore, clustered index, heap) and what resource class is associated with the user trying to run the `COPY INTO` command.

Comment: It is an internal table with clustered columnstore set to round-robin. I am not sure about the DWU setting though but it should be in the low range as this is a development box.

Comment: You’re using a wildcard there - try just one file.  Does that work?  Maybe there is a problem with one of the files, narrow it down.

Comment: This might be because of insufficient size. Can you try altering the database Maxsize property? Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&tabs=sqlpool#overview-azure-synapse-analytics)